# Simulate bus-off using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, bus, canoe

Simulating busoff using CAPL.

Usually we create busoff using Shorting CANH & CANL, CANH to GND, CANL to VBAT, etc.

But here I want to create busoff using the CAPL functions?

Is it possible to simulate busoff using CAPL or any other way (not psychically)? If yes, please suggest.

Thank you.